# Realm database locking?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-cocoa

On sync I overwrite all my local data with the server's data. For this I first call `realm.delete(realm.objects(MyObj))` for all my objects. Then I save the response's objects with `realm.add(obj, update: false)`. Everything is in a single transaction. The payload can take a while to process but it's not big enough to justify implementing pagination.

Can the user use the app normally during this process? Can they store new items that are deleted in the clearing part of the transaction, or that would trigger an error or be overwritten during the adding part? If yes how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

Realm uses a Multi-Version-Concurrency-Control algorithm. This uses locks to ensure exclusive write, while other threads can keep reading previous versions of the data. We have an [article on our blog](https://academy.realm.io/posts/threading-deep-dive/), which explains how that works in more depth.

Be aware that what you attempt to solve here is a non-trivial challenge.

> Can they store new items that are deleted in the clearing part of the transaction, or that would trigger an error or be overwritten during the adding part?

While the background transaction is in progress, other write transactions would be blocked. If you do these writes from the main thread, you would block the main thread. If you do them from background threads, they would queue up and be executed after your sync transaction is completed.

The objects, which are deleted in the beginning would become inaccessible (which you can check via `invalidated`), because write transactions always operate on the latest version. If your objects have consistent primary keys across your sync operations, you can utilize those to re-fetch them and redo all modifications to the fresh instances. But note, that you need to store the primary keys (and all other object data) into memory, before beginning the write transaction, which implies an implicit refresh.

Comment: Thanks! if I understand correctly I'd have to 1. Put the complete sync call (including the remote request) inside a background transaction so possible write operations during sync are queued after it and 2. rewrite all my writes to check if the object has been invalidated and fetch it again if yes, such that they still can be executed normally if sync updated the db in between?

Comment: Currently I just block the UI (with a progress overlay) during sync, to avoid overwriting possible writes during this time. This is of course not very good UX and looking how I can improve this.

Comment: Actually, I don't need the invalidated check as I don't hold references to results. I instantiate a new Realm for each query.

Comment: Be careful with that. Realm instances are cached per thread internally, because it used to be relatively expensive to instantiate them for the first time on a thread. So if they are keep retained, they are not necessarily up-to-date.

Comment: I use GCD like described here https://realm.io/docs/swift/0.92.0/ (updated to the latest Realm version in the meantime, but kept this architecture), so this should not be a problem? All I want to know is what is the best approach to solve my sync problem without blocking the UI, is simply putting everything including the remote call in a (background, using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue`) write block a good idea?